# Tableau: Adding Conditional Mark on Text Table with Null Dates

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on a text table that has a shape/ color mark based on whether an employee was working that day or was off.  I'm having an issue adding a mark on dates where there are no values for the employee.

[image: Text Table]

In this example, I'd like to assign 'Off'  ( blue X)  to John from April 3 to April 9 and 'Off' to Jessica from April 4 to April 5.   Everything else should be 'Working'  (green X)

This is what I started with:

```
IF ( ATTR([Name]) =  'John' AND MIN([Date]) >= #04/03/2018#) then 'OFF'  
else 'WORKING' end
```

I'm having an issue with the nulls and am unsure of how to approach it. I tried adding

```
IFNULL(LOOKUP(SUM([Number of Records]),0),0) = 0
```

but no success. I added the workbook below if anyone could assist!

https://public.tableau.com/profile/a.ganady

Comment: Hi - are you defining 'off' in your data or just in Tableau? I;d approach this by making `1` the most common value, e.g. 'Working', so that you have no cells with a `null` value.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response- my issue is that there are certain days that should be colored differently regardless of the value. In the example image, I'd like to classify 'Off' (in blue) for John between April 3 to 9. Please note that April 10 does not have data but should be classified as working (and April 3 has data but is classified as off)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fill up all null values with blue marks, you dont need any formula.
[image]

The trick here is to enable Analysis > Table Layout > Show Empty Columns
[image]

Also note that you can show a different shape for null values.
[image]

Comment: To clarify terminology, you aren’t using a different mark type in the last step. The mark type is shape. But you are using a different shape based on sum(number of records). You can avoid having to assign a shape for each positive value bye writing a calculated field to return like isnulll(count(1))

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response and the mark clarification- my issue is that there are certain days that should be colored differently regardless of the value. In the example image, I'd like to classify 'Off' (in blue) for John between April 3 to 9. Please note that April 10 does not have data but should be classified as working (and April 3 has data but is classified as off)

Comment: @AlexBlakemore, agree. I was using mark type in the literal sense. corrected.

Comment: @A.Ganady, How does the system know when to use a different color? You need some kind of logic for that. Are you planning to hard code the color for every date in a calculation?

Comment: @JoseCherian Yes, I have a list of dates to hard code. Essentially if the date exists in the list it would be color A, everything else would be color B (regardless of any data values). I've tried a simple calculated field but if the date/name combination  does not exist in the data, the display is null.

Comment: @A.Ganady, you can still use the same technic. Use data blending to link to your hard coded dates and assign a color to those values and a different  color for everything else.